# Prove that set of regularisable sample paths is measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I am currently working through Rogers and Williams Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales Volume 1 (or rather lecture notes based on it) and am unable to understand the proof of corollary II.62.12:

> If $\{Y_q: q\in\mathbb{Q}^+\}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued stochastic process carried by $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$ then $G:=\{\omega: q\rightarrow Y_q(\omega)\text{ is regularisable }\}\in\mathcal{G}$

> Proof: The previous theorem allows us to exhibit $G$ as a $\sigma$-cylinder, which is then automatically in $\mathcal{G}$. Do think this through.

where the preceding theorem states that

> Let $y:\mathbb{Q}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $y$ is regularisable if and only if whenever $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $a<b$ we have both $\sup\{|y_q|: q\in\mathbb{Q}^+\cap[0,N]\}<\infty$ and $U_N(y;[a,b])<\infty$

where $U_N(y;[a,b])$ is the number of upcrossings of $y$ in $[a,b]$. Additionally, $\sigma$-cylinders for $\mathbb{R}$-valued processes with $\mathbb{Q}^+$-time are defined as those elements of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{Q}^+}$ that can be written as $\pi_S^{-1}A_S$ where $S$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{Q}^+$ and $A_S\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^S$ (which I'm pretty sure is just any element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{Q}^+}$)

Whilst I do understand the theorem, I do not understand what the proof of the corollary has to do with it. I also don't see how $G$ can be a $\sigma$-cylinder since it is supposed to be an element of $\mathcal{G}$ and not of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{Q}^+}$. Our professor did say that we have to take countable intersections and then see that these are still in the $\sigma$-algebra, but I do not see which elements of which $\sigma$-algebra we're supposed to be intersecting.

Edit: after thinking about the corollary for a bit I'm fairly certain that the intersections my professor was hinting at were $$\bigcap_{N\in\mathbb{N}, a<b\in\mathbb{Q}}\{\omega: q\rightarrow Y_q(\omega) \text{ satisfies } U_N(y;[a,b])<\infty\}$$ intersected with $$\bigcap_{N\in\mathbb{N}, a<b\in\mathbb{Q}}\{\omega: q\rightarrow Y_q(\omega) \text{ satisfies } \sup\{|y_q|: q\in\mathbb{Q}^+\cap[0,N]\}<\infty\}$$ though that still leaves me unsure how to prove that $\{\omega: q\rightarrow Y_q(\omega) \text{ satisfies } U_N(y;[a,b])<\infty\}\in\mathcal{G}$ for $N\in\mathbb{N}, a<b\in\mathbb{Q}$ (and the same for the other property).